# Copying and pasting rows in a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble copying rows from multiple sheets to a new worksheet. The code I now have is as following:

```
     Sub Samenvoegen()

 Dim J As Integer


On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add ' add a sheet in first place
Sheets(1).Name = "Index"

' work through sheets
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count ' from sheet 2 to last sheet
    Sheets(J).Activate ' make the sheet active
    Range("2:2").Select
    Range(Selection, Cells(Rows.Count, "2:2").End(xlUp)).Copy Range("2:2") ' select all cells in this sheets

    ' select all lines except title
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select

    ' copy cells selected in the new sheet on last line
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
    Next
    End Sub
```

For example: I have 10 worksheets in my excel file and if I use this macro, it merges row 2 from all those excel worksheets into 1 worksheet named "Index" and pastes per worksheet under each other. Thats what I want. But the problem with this macro is that it copies the second row from the first worksheet correct. But after that first worksheet it copies from B2 from the second worksheet and C2 from the third worksheet and so on..

I would like to have a macro which copies all of the second row from the worksheets and pastes it into the new worksheet under each other. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Sub Samenvoegen()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, i As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    wb.Sheets.Add ' add a sheet in first place
    wb.Sheets(1).Name = "Index"
    
    ' work through sheets
    i = 1
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets ' from sheet 2 to last sheet
        If ws.Name <> "Index" Then
            ' copy row(2) into the new sheet
            ws.Rows(2).Copy 
            wb.Sheets("Index").Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @CDP1802, thanks for your reply! This works for me. I forgot to mention that the copied rows are formulas. Is there a way to add PasteValues to this formula? I've seen multiple VBA codes about this, but I don't know where to add them in this formula.